# Is there a way to watch Netflix instantly on an iBook G4 (powerpc)

Tags: powerpc

I have an old iBook G4 running 10.4.11 and I want to be able to watch Netflix instantly. The problem is that Netflix only supports intel based macs. I'm curious to know if anyone has found a work around for this problem.

I have followed this [tutorial to install silverlight 2 on a ppc](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3707/mac-os-x-install-silverlight-2-on-non-intel-systems-ie-powerpc-or-osx86-installs/), and that was a success. However, Netflix still doesn't allow me to stream movies. I'm trying with both Firefox and Safari. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

According to Neflix, the minimum requirements are:

An Intel-based Mac with OS 10.4.11 or later
Safari 3 or higher; or Firefox 3 or higher &
1 GB RAM

Comment: Can you provide a reference link to where the requirements are for netflix, to make the answer nicer.

Comment: IIRC, having used a G4 iBook for years, this was in part due to the lack of Microsoft Silverlight for PPC.